# react-native. my app installer doesnot place the app icon on the main screen

Tags: android, react-native, apk

When installing on Android, it does not add a shortcut on home screen. You can find it in the app drawer only now. How to add icon of the app on the home android screen?

Comment: Maybe it's related with your phone

Comment: Try to add a shortcut.

Comment: Post your code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a property of phone and has nothing to do with your specific app. What happens when you install other new apps from the PlayStore?

There is a setting in PlayStore where you can choose to automatically add newly installed app to the Home screen. Try changing that.